# Adding a static picture to a Folium map

Tags: image, folium

I'd like to add a add a static picture to my Folium map. I tried following the instructions [found](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/1093) [here](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/1093), but for some reason things go wrong.

It works well when I use the exact same url (from the second hyperlink, above), but when I replace it with my own, an image with a "?" is added to the map. For instance, I tried replacing the url with

```
https://imgur.com/a/odmnKy6
```

or with

```
https://github.com/maxmuller100/ideas/blob/master/Screenshot%202021-05-30%20at%2015.34.50.jpg
```

Both links contain the same image I uploaded. However, they're not shown in my map once I upload (either of) by putting the url in the code.

**Question**: What should I do differently to properly insert the image into the Folium map?

Comment: Please show your relevant lines of code.